# Perform awk equivalant with Sublime Text

Tags: awk, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

With Sublime Text 3, is it possible to modify an opened file to keep only a given column ?

For instance I have an file with this content:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

I would like Sublime Text to transform this file content in:

```
a
b
c
d
```

On Linux I can achieve it easily with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1}' filename
```

I'm curious if I can achieve the same with Sublime Text 3, and being able to specify a column number and/or a delimiter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sublime Text 3 you can do a search and replace employing a regular expression. Replace:  `.*$` with blank.

- <kbd>CTRL+H</kbd> open Search and Replace
- <kbd>ALT+R</kbd> enable regular expressions
- Find: `.*$` note the space at the beginning
- Replace: blank
- <kbd>CTRL+ALT+ENTER</kbd> replace all

Of course it's not the same as AWK, and not as easy for some use cases.